# Tag synonym / merge request: [zelda-series] » [legend-of-zelda-series]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-rename-request

I'd like to request that [zelda-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-series) be made a synonym of and/or be merged into [legend-of-zelda-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-zelda-series). [legend-of-zelda-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-zelda-series) better represents the actual name of the series and fits the tag character limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.

<sub>Sometimes 5 characters are really enough.</sub>

Comment: Could have done it in two: OK